# YOLO v4 darknet stopped training

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, yolo

I've been training my object detection model for hours in google colab and it stopped training suddenly without finishing all the epochs and I can see that I'm not in that runtime either (The git clone of darknet is not showing in the directories too). Is there any way so that I can get the weights that have been trained so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the weights that you have been trained so far, you can try to follow [this tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmj3nxGT2YQ). There you can find how to do it.

Or you can directly refer to [this reference](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/7308#issuecomment-770612710) from Alexey github to save every weight you like.

Comment: I followed this one, actually the problem was I put the backup weights in darknet cloned directory. Later I set the backup directory to my google drive and it got saved. That was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No, the weights are almost certainly gone. The VMs in Colab have a limited lifetime and the runtimes have limited resources, and if any are exceeded the VM is recycled. You can read more at the [Colab FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html).

Comment: Any way to save the weights after a certain time for backup?

Comment: Depending on what framework you use, there may be a callback for that or you may be able to write your own custom callback that saves things back to your drive after each epoch.